# Properties of the mean of a predictor function

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, modeling, bias-variance-tradeoff

I am learning about the bias-variance tradeoff, and my question is about the properties of the function $E_{D_n}(\hat f(x)) $ which appears inside both the $variance$ and $bias^2$ terms. I am looking at the statement of the theorem as it appears [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~smyth/courses/cs274/readings/xing_singh_CMU_bias_variance.pdf) (screenshot below).

[image]

Here $\hat f(x)$ is the predictive model, $D_n$ is a set of training data with $n$ observations, and $E_{D_n}$ is the expectation over all training sets $D_n$.

My question is about the expression $E_{D_n}[\hat f(X)]$. What can we say about $g(x):= E_{D_n}[\hat f(x)]$? For example, does $g$ have the same form as $\hat f$?

Let me clarify how I am interpreting the expression for $g$ and how I would evaluate $g(x)$ for a fixed $x$.

Assumptions:

1. $X$ is a random variable (often a vector). $x$ is a possible value of $X$.
2. $D_n$ is a random variable taking values in the product space ${\prod_{i=1}^n}(X,Y)_i$ We can think of it as a $nx2$ matrix with n rows $(X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2), ..., (X_n, Y_n)$. Here, $(X_i, Y_i)$ is the $ith$ observation. Each observation comes from the same distribution - the distribution of $(X,Y)$. Let $\hat \delta = [(x,y)_i]_{i=1..n}$ represent a possible value of $D_n$, and let $\rho(\hat \delta)$ be the density of $D_n$.
3. $\hat f$ is a function of the random variable $D_n$. We can think of it as a vector of coefficients $\theta = (\theta_1,..,\theta_m)$ together with a predetermined model form, something like $\hat f(x) = \theta_0 +{\theta_1}{x_1} +{\theta_2}{x_2}$ or $\hat f(x) = \theta_0 +{\theta_1}{x_1}^2$. $\theta$ is a function of the random variable $D_n$, but the particular model form is fixed in advance.
4. Since $\hat f(X)$ is a function of $X$ and $D_n$, I will write $\hat f(X,D_n)$. For a particular training set and value of X, this becomes $\hat f(x,\hat \delta)$.

Given all of that, here is how I would calculate $g(x)$:

$g(x) := E_{D_n}[\hat f(x)] = \int \hat f(x,D_n)dD_n = \int \hat f(x,\hat \delta)\rho(\hat \delta) d\hat \delta$

> **My question is:  What does $g$ look like? For example, if $\hat f(x)$ is linear, is $g$ linear too? Is it continuous? How does it depend on the underlying distributions of X and Y? What do we know about it?**